# How to extract class name or id from the object?

Tags: javascript

From my understanding it's good practice to keep all your DOM selectors inside an object, because if the html is modified, you only need to change that object instead of looking through the entire code. However, how do you get a class name or a id from that object?

Example of what I used to do.
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vvLoqJ?editors=1111

*What I'am trying to do:*

Obviously is not going to work because I attempting to add string with object. But if there is a way to add that string class place so that button 2 would work without modifying elements object. Thank you in advance.
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WLweom?editors=1111

HTML

```
<button class = "button--roll">First Roll</button>
<button class = "button--roll-2">Second Roll</button>
```

SCRIPT

```
const elements = {
    buttonRoll: document.querySelector(".button--roll"),
};
class buttonRoll{
    constructor(){
        // Properties
        this.buttonRoll = elements.buttonRoll;
        //    Methods
        this.events;
    }
    events(){
        let roll = "-2";
        // this.buttonRoll + roll.addEventListener('click', () => this.buttonRoll2());
        console.log(this.buttonRoll);
    }
    buttonRoll2(){
        console.log("second button is clicked");
    }
}
buttonRoll = new buttonRoll;
buttonRoll.events();
```

Comment: "from my understanding it's good practice to keep all your DOM selectors inside an object, because if html is modified, you only need to change that object instead of looking through entire code" it seems kinda out there to label this 'best practice'...nor have I ever heard that before. Why are you reinventing jQuery?

Comment: You show here why it's not always good practice, since all instances of buttonRoll will refer to the same button instead of two seperate buttons. So `this.buttonRoll = document.querySelector( someUniqueSelector )` would work better if you plan to have multiple buttons.

Comment: there are much simpler methods to achieve this scenario, why dont you make use of that.

Comment: @Jared Smith: I learned this practice from Jonas Schmedtmann - udemy instructor. [His github](https://github.com/jonasschmedtmann/complete-javascript-course/blob/master/9-forkify/final/src/js/views/base.js).

Comment: @ArnasDičkus  It'll only be a best practice for static HTML elements that will not get rerendered during the usage of a page. If you look at the other view examples in his code, the elements object containing already selected nodes is only used for the menu, where the actual event handlers use document.querySelector() directly to find the correct non-menu elements, eg. the dynamic ones that get rerendered.

Comment: @Shilly I guess you right. It seems I took this practice too literal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in this case, by using your  const element :

```js
    const elements = {
        buttonRoll: document.querySelector(".button--roll"),
    };

    class buttonRoll {
      constructor() {

        let base_ClassName = elements.buttonRoll.className;

        this.button_1 = elements.buttonRoll;
        this.button_2 = document.querySelector('.'+base_ClassName+'-2');

        this.button_1.onclick = (e)=>this.button_x_click(e);
        this.button_2.onclick = (e)=>this.button_x_click(e);
      }
      button_x_click(e){
        console.log(e.target.className);
      }
    }

    buttonRolls = new buttonRoll();
```

```html
    <button class = "button--roll">First Roll</button>

    <button class = "button--roll-2">Second Roll</button>
```

Comment: Yes this would solve my problem. Although talking with @Shilly I came to a conclusion. That using object elements is not always the best practice. And I should just use querry selectors.

Answer (score 0):

you're looking for something like that ?

```js
    class buttonRoll {
      constructor(base_ClassName) {
        this.button_1 = document.querySelector('.'+base_ClassName);
        this.button_2 = document.querySelector('.'+base_ClassName+'-2');

        this.button_1.onclick = (e)=>this.button_1_click(e);
        this.button_2.onclick = (e)=>this.button_2_click(e);

      }
      button_1_click(e){
        console.log('button_1_click');
      }
      button_2_click(e){
        console.log('button_2_click');
      }
    }

    buttonRolls = new buttonRoll('button--roll');
```

```html
    <button class = "button--roll">First Roll</button>

    <button class = "button--roll-2">Second Roll</button>
```

Comment: It's close but I was expecting to leave document.querySelectors inside my const elements object. I was thinking more towards: selecting object class and adding it. In my example console.log(this.buttonRoll). Will give you "<button class='button--roll'>First Roll</button>". I was thinking whether it's possible to select only class "button-roll" and connect it with a string -2